# LINQ Union - string keep orderby

Tags: c#, linq, union

```
return new List<string> { newItem }.Union(currentList.Take(9));
```

How do I keep newItem at the top? This seems very simple but Im having a brain freeze.

It naturally orders the strings, meaning my newItem can appear anywhere in the list. I `currentList.Remove(newItem);` just incase it has already been in there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use `Concat` instead of `Union`, the former should keep the order whereas the latter is a set method which removes duplicates and does not guarantee any order:

```
return new List<string> { newItem }.Concat(currentList.Take(9));
```

That applies to `Linq-To-Objects` as stated [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341731.aspx):

> When the object returned by this method is enumerated, Union
>   enumerates first and second in that order and yields each element that
>   has not already been yielded.

But it also applies to database driven LINQ providers as `Linq-To-Sql` or `Linq-To-Entities` since `UNION ALL` and `UNION` behave similar (the former keeps order, the latter not).